# Kendo checkbox treeview with dropdowns and datepickers

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview, kendo-dropdown, kendo-datepicker

I need to make a Kendo TreeView with a design like this:

[image]

I was writing this code: http://dojo.telerik.com/eZAMU

It's work well, but dropdown lists and datepickers are closing very quickly and I haven't time to select something